# Using R, How to obtain "dbo" parameters on SQL Server database?

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I have a SQL Server database, in spanish, and I want to obtain the results from SELECT * table.name

To do this, I connect R with the database using odbc library.

After that, I do this:

```
dbSendQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[table.name]")
```

This returns me an error: std::bad_alloc

But if I do this:

```
dbSendQuery(con,"SELECT Id FROM [database].[dbo].[table.name]")
```

then I obtain good results

I have seen that only when varchar type of column names are involved in the query, then the error is shown, so I think that schema could be the responsible of this issue.

What can I do to don't have this error? The schema is "dbo"

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are sending `table.name` and it works? That implies your schema is `table` and your table is called `name`

Comment: Yes, If I use the code to obtain Id, I get the Id, but if I want to obtain another kind of data from varchar column, then an error is displayed

Comment: No, that's not possible. Please read my question again. What is your table called? For example `SELECT Id FROM dbo.table` will work, but neither of the ones you show above will.

Comment: Well, the complete code is dbSendQuery(con,"SELECT Id FROM [database].[dbo].[table.name]") I edit the entry post

Comment: Don't post code in comments, instead [edit] your question to be more complete.

Comment: Ok @DavidG, done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what your client environment is, I had a similar issue with ODBC + R + **Linux** + **Sybase**. I was able to query numeric columns but not character columns, receiving the same `std::bad_alloc` error. Your `Id` field is likely a number, while `SELECT *` is pulling in other columns with character data types.

The solution for me was to make sure I was using an ODBC driver that supports an 8-bytes SQLLEN datatype. On Linux running the command `odbcinst -j` showed me that the SQLLEN Size was 8 for my installed unixODBC version 2.3.1 running on RHEL Server 7.5 64-bit.

By default the Sybase driver was symlinked to the 4-bytes version. Following the instructions below I made sure I was linking to the 8-bytes version and my problems were solved. Oddly I never experienced these issues when issuing commands via `isql`. Perhaps your SQL Server driver might be impacted in the same way.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20155.1600/doc/html/san1361915533650.html

Posted this also in one of the related GitHub issues:
https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/174#issuecomment-403106647